# Item ID doesn't match the list item number

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a SharePoint list for which I need to open with a custom Edit Form using the item ID, but I notice that the item number doesn't match the ID. For example:when I access the list using REST:

```
_api/lists/getbytitle('Situation')/items
```

It lists the list items properties, including the ID (Item 8 in this case):

[image]

Notice that in this case the Id number is (8). When I open the list in SharePoint, there is no such item with an ID=8, it stops at 6:

[image]

This is becoming an issue when In try to edit the record using:

```
...Situation/editRecord.aspx?ID='+id
```

I get an error, because these is no item with ID=8. On the other hand if I just try `_api/lists/getbytitle('Situation')/items(8)`, just to check, it shows the correct item. I've never seen this before. What could be happening here? If more details are  needed, please let me know. thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you doing all of this as the same user? This behavior matches what you'd expect if you were using two accounts, where one didn't have the same permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try use filter instead

```
/web/lists/GetByTitle('Situation')/items?$filter=ID eq 8
```